# ImageResizer S3Reader2

Tags: imageresizer

I am running imageResizer 3.4.3.103 and I have installed S3Reader2 fresh from nuget.  This is a fresh installation of imageResizer using nuget and when I run the application using S3Reader2 I get the following error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK, Version=2.0.2.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

This is my web.config file:  I'm hiding the bucket names and accesskeys for obvious reasons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
</httpModules></system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
</modules>
</system.webServer><resizer>
<plugins>
  <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
  <add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
<add name="SimpleFilters" />
<add name="S3Reader2" prefix="~/medias" buckets="*" accessKeyId="*" secretAccessKey="*" />

</plugins>
</resizer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="AWSSDK" publicKeyToken="9f476d3089b52be3" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already installed an older version of AWSSDK. You need to update the AWSSDK package via NuGet.